# Regex that checks that a string should not start or end with a space and should not end with a dot (.)

Tags: regex, space

As per the requirement I need to generate a regex to match a String that doesn't start or end with space. Apart from that the string should not end with a special character dot(.). As per my understanding I've generated a regex `"\\S(.*\\S)?$"` which restrict the string that has a space at the beginning and at the end of the string. With this expression I need to validate the regex for string that ends with dot. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: means the string should not end with either space or `.`..right??

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am working in java .

Comment: `^\S.*[^.\s]$`....

Comment: The string shouldn't start or end with space

Comment: @AnoojAgarwal what about `.`?

Comment: apart from that it should'nt end with a dot (.)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pA7kI1/1

Comment: THnaks Pranav it worked

Comment: This pattern doesn't work for a single character string. It returns a false.
Please suggest a pattern which would work irrespective of size of the String.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following regex

```
^\S.*[^.\s]$
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/pA7kI1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

If you want to match single character then you can use [look-ahead and look behind-assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?=\S).+(?<=[^.\s])$
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/pA7kI1/4)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

If look-behind not supports then use

```
^(?=\S).*[^.\s]$
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/pA7kI1/5)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: /^\S.*[^.\s]$
/ This is good, but requires at least to chars to pass (i.e. wouldn't work for validating at least one char, with no trailing or leading spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern: `^[^\ ].*[^\ .]$`

Here is a demonstration:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(" This string starts with a space");
        list.add("This string ends with a space ");
        list.add("This string ends with a dot.");
        list.add("This string ends with a newline\n");
        list.add("\tThis string starts with a tab character");

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^\\ ].*[^\\ .]$");

        for (String s : list) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if (m.find())
                System.out.printf("\"%s\" - Passed!\n", s);
            else
                System.out.printf("\"%s\" - Didn't pass!\n", s);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
" This string starts with a space" - Didn't pass!
"This string ends with a space " - Didn't pass!
"This string ends with a dot." - Didn't pass!
"This string ends with a newline
" - Passed!
"   This string starts with a tab character" - Passed!
```